# Two-way binding in QML user control

Tags: qt, mvvm, qml, qt-quick

I'm making a user control which has a property, which I modify with functions. The property is binded to another property in Main.qml file. In a real-life project, it is binded to a property of a ViewModel. I need to have a two-way binding allowing me to change the ViewModel's property from qml view and the view's property from the view model.

Main.qml:

```
property int myProperty: 0

Column {
    MyControl {
        value: myProperty
    }
    MouseArea {
        width: 200; height: 100
        onClicked: myProperty = 0
    }
}
```

MyControl.qml:

```
Item {
    id: root
    property int value: 0
    Row {
        MouseArea {
            width: 100; height: 100
            onClicked: root.value++
        }
        MouseArea {
            width: 100; height: 100
            onClicked: root.value--
        }
    }
}
```

But in fact, when I change MyControl's `value` property with `root.value++`, it brokes the binding and the changes stop passing between the properties.

Is there a way to implement it in a declarative way, without cross-setting it by ...Changed signals?

Comment: I think it is also solved with a `...Changed` signal or other names in Qt components themselves, but I'd like to hear better solutions if possible

Comment: I don't see the definition of the property `value` in MyControl.qml, which you use in both files. Should it be changed to `myProperty`? Also [this link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript) might be helpful

Comment: About the `value` property definition -- it was a mistake, I've fixed it.

Comment: And concerning the link: Thank you, I'd seen it when I posted the question. They offer to use a couple of `Binding { }` objects, which doesn't look natural and can be a source of errors (when you change one place and forget to change the second one), but that topic is 4 years old, and I hope, that something has changed now

Comment: Depending on the needs of your app, you could simply change the definition of `myProperty` to be an alias: `property alias myProperty: myControl.value`.

Comment: If think the solution for you is to just use signals. Since you want to change an external variable inside your component, which he can not know anything about. Signals like `incrementValue()` and `decrementValue()` or `increaseValue(int val)` and `decreaseValue(int val)` and just do whatever you want in slots `onIncrement...` where your Component is used.